# how does BufferedReader keep track of what line has been read?

Tags: java, file-io, readline, bufferedreader

I'm reading lines from a file, and I believe that once I've read all the lines, I get an exception because of my while loop condition.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liarliar.main(liarliar.java:79)
```

... the code...

```
// read the first line of the file
iNumMembers = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim()); 

// read file
while ((sLine = br.readLine().trim()) != null) {

    // extract the name and value 'm'
    String[] split = sLine.split("\\s+");
    sAccuser = split[0];
    iM = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
    saTheAccused = new String[iM];

    for (int i = 0; i < iM; i++) {
        saTheAccused[i] = br.readLine().trim();
    }

    // create member
    // initialize name and number of members being accused
    Member member = new Member();
    member.setName(sAccuser);
    member.setM(iM);
    member.setAccused(saTheAccused);

    veteranMembers.add(member);
}
```

The for loop inside will have to read several lines so if the last line of the file is read, then the while will try to `readLine()` and that will fail because the whole file has been read. So how does the `BufferedReader readLine()` work and how can I safely exit my while loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readLine()` returns null on EOF, and you are trying to call `trim()` on a null reference.  Move the call to `trim()` inside the loop, as in

```
// read file
while ((sLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

    // extract the name and value 'm'
    String[] split = sLine.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Actually I just realized that I'm using the regex to ignore whitespace... so the trim() is useless right?

Comment: No, if the input has leading blanks the result array will contain an empty string as the first element (index [0]).  If you don't want this behavior, you must still trim().  If this seems illogical, consider what you would want if the delimiter was a comma and you were splitting the string ",a,b,c".  In that case you would probably want to know that the first "field" was empty.